# Is it possible to require only one of two parameters in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor

I know that I can require one parameter using `@required` like below :

```
class Foo{
  String firstParam;
  String secondParam;
  Foo({@required this.firstParam, this.secondParam});
}
```

However, I don't know how to require only one of the two parameters without requiring both. I have something that looks like what I want using `assert` :

```
class Foo{
  String firstParam;
  String secondParam;

  Foo({this.firstParam, this.secondParam}): assert(this.firstParam != null || this.secondParam!= null);
}
```

But it doesn't warn me in VS Code and `asserts` are not used in Release mode.

Is there some way to do it in Dart?

Answer (score 7):

Use this and provide a message for your assertion:

```
class Foo {
  String firstParam;
  String secondParam;

  Foo({this.firstParam, this.secondParam})
      : assert(
          (firstParam != null || secondParam != null),
          'One of the parameters must be provided',
        );
}
```

Warning if none of the parameters is provided:

[image]

Comment: It is not exactly what I want since it is not used in Release mode (I already use assertions). I also would prefer not be able to compile my app if one of the params is not provided. Here, I can compile but it will throw an exception if I didn't provide one parameter.

Comment: What to do if BOTH parameters are provided? how to restrict that? I tried && but it's confusing

Comment: @Hardik The assert is passed a bool and a String. If the bool is NOT true then the assertion error is thrown.  Admittedly it's a bit confusing.  Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible, though you could make both parameters to be required and set explicitly to null if it is needed